# NFS Shares (Windows using FreeNFS but connecting on Linux)

Tags: nfs, raspberry-pi

I am using a "FreeNFS" on a Windows 8.1 machine and I set up a share `I:\Library`. I am currently allowing all clients and using ANSI encoding.

My Linux box is actually a Raspberry Pi, using Raspbmc. I am currently SSHing into the machine and trying to mount the share with no success.

I created a directory to mount:
`sudo mkdir /nas`

and here is the command I am using to mount it:
`sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.2:/Library /nas`

I've checked my windows firewall (turned it off completely while attempting this) and the error I am getting is: `mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.2:Library`

I am not really sure where to move on from here, FreeNFS can't be blocked by a firewall because there is none, and that mount command is as basic as it gets. I'm kind of stuck at the moment.

I even tried `sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.2:/Library /nas -o nfsvers=3` because I *think* FreeNFS uses version 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No security?

Try disabling authentication when mounting the FreeNFS share on your Rasp Pi system:

```
$ sudo mount -v -t nfs -o nfsvers=3,sec=none 192.168.1.2:/Library /nas
```

#### NFS client software installed?

Also make sure that you have the NFS client side software stack installed too. Directions on how to  do this are covered here in this Raspian FAQ, titled: [How do I mount directories from other Linux/Unix/BSD servers? How do I mount an NFS](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianFAQ#How_do_I_mount_directories_from_other_Linux.2FUnix.2FBSD_servers.3F__How_do_I_mount_an_NFS_share.3F).

```
$ sudo aptitude install nfs-common portmap
```

Then start `rpcbind`:

```
$ sudo service rpcbind start
```

If you want it to start at boot:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d rpcbind enable
```

#### References

- [Anyone have FreeNFS working?](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=166599)

Comment: that didn't help unfortunately. `trying 192.168.1.2 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049` `portmap query failed: RPC: Authentication error`. The problem is I am not 100% sure that FreeNFS is even working. I read that trying to telnet to it on port 111 (port FreeNFS, or NFS for that matter) listens on, but all putty does is exit immediately.

Comment: @Rakshasas - see updates, Do you have NFS packages etc. installed on the Rasp Pi?

Comment: I was fairly sure raspbmc had it but I double checked. `dpkg-query -l '*nfs*'` revealed nfs-client, nfs-common and nfs-kernel-ser to be installed. I have actually seen that link already, wasn't able to make much use of it. Also I received "Starting rpcbind daemon... Already running.." so looks like that isn't it.

Comment: @Rakshasas - you have to also start the rpcbind service too. That's how NFS works, it's making remote procedure calles (RPC) to the other system.

Comment: `rpcbind is already the newest version` as well. I think I am going to try and find some alternatives to FreeNFS and see where that takes me.

Comment: @Rakshasas - I wasn't asking about  the package `rpcbind`, being up to date, I meant the service `rpcbind` needs to be running. Did you run this cmd? `sudo service rpcbind start`? You should be able to see the mounts on a system if it's working like this: `showmount -e 192.168.1.2`.

Comment: Sorry I was just being thorough. I received the message that rpcbind was already running. Looks like I figured it out though. Can't get FreeNFS to work, but using a trail of haneWIN, and using `192.168.1.2:/i/Library` got it to work. Video is a bit stuttery though.

Answer (score 1):

FreeNFS exports the directory you specify as the root folder as "/", so in your case you would need:

```
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.2:/ /nas
```

It took me a while to figure this one out myself :)

Answer (score 0):

I used hanewin as Win NFS server and mounted on it from Raspberry Pi 2 Jessie.

My notes are not complete, so you will have challenges and need to look up more info.

Windows: Download and install hanewin. Modify `C:\Program Files\nfsd\exports` file.

I needed only one line: `E:\hanewin -alldirs -public -umask:000` in this file.
Restart NFS Server from Windows services to bring changes to effect.
Add hanewin to Windows firewall's allowed programs, 3 executables in 
`c:\program files\nfsd` folder.

Raspberry PI:

```
sudo apt-get install nsf-common portmap
nfs-kernel-server
```

There was some other configuration related to start the services and RCP,
sorry no notes about that. To get that in PI: `cd`, `mkdir mynfstest`,
`sudo mount 192.168.1.229:/e/hanewin mynfstest`. (`/e/` is windows `E:`, 
numeric address is my Win 10) .